# erro xampp no linux ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, apache-cordova, composer, mapas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro ao atualizar o composer , por favor alguem pode me ajudar.

Comment: A pergunta não tem nada haver com apache-cordova e nem com a tag mapas, não use tags que não tem haver com o problema. Não poste imagens quando se é possivel copiar o output do console. Motivos: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635

Answer (score 1):

O `coffecode/uploader` esta deixando bem claro, precisa habilitar o GD, o GD é nativo do PHP.

Se for PHP 5.6 instale assim:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

Se for 7.0 PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

Se for 7.1 PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
```

Se for 7.2 PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

Se for 7.3 PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd
```

Se for 7.4 PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd
```

E assim por diante conforme lançarem versões novas

Comment: ou `sudo apt-get install php-gd` para instalar a versão padrão do sistema.

Comment: @gmsantos não sou usuário de Ubuntu, usou debian e CentOS, mas se me recordo em Debian ao menos tive sim que especificar a versão, não porque tenho mais de uma instalado, mas desde a primeira, ou posso estar me confundindo, em Ubuntu não sei afirmar, talvez tenha me baseado em outro, mas o efeito é o mesmo e talvez assim evite conflito com multiplas versões.

Comment: Ambas distros aceitam a versão padrão: https://i.stack.imgur.com/91rbj.png

Comment: @gmsantos entáo vale o que falei depois, se outro futuro usuário que vier aqui com múltiplas versões não sofrerá com conflitos, o que geralmente ocorre de ter uma vesão do php5.x e outra do php7.x